# Android - Using custom View in Widget

Tags: android, view, widget

i made a extended a View, overwrote the 3 View Contructors and tried to insert it on my xml of a widget.

The Exception is:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.myView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4001e710

is it possible to use custom views in Widgets?

Answer (score 12):

> is it possible to use custom views in
>   Widgets?

If by "Widgets" you mean "app widgets", then, no. [You cannot use custom `View` classes in app widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

Answer (score 2):

But you could use an ImageView which is supported in a widget:

1. Create a Bitmap and draw with a Canvas on it:

```java
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidht, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
canvas.drawText("test", 0, 30, new Paint());
```

2. Assign this bitmap to ImageView in the widget by using

```java
remoteViews.setImageBitmap(viewID, mBitmap);
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062559/android-appwidget-with-custom-view-not-working) for more information