# Android: AppWidget with custom view not working

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating a appwidget that consists of a single custom view called Foo.

xml/widget.xml:

```
<appwidget-provider
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:minWidth="294dp"
 android:minHeight="72dp"
 android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
 android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout">
</appwidget-provider>
```

layout/widget_layout

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <package.name.Foo
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Foo:

```
  public class Foo extends View 
  {..}
```

I tested the `Foo` view in a normal android app, and it works perfectly. However, when I try to run the widget I get `"error while loading widget"`. When I remove the `Foo` view from the widget, everything is fine. So it has something to do with the `Foo` view.

Unfortunately I can't get any more specific errors in DDMS, cause I don't know of a way to debug widgets.

I would like to know if it is indeed possible to use your own custom views in a app-widget?
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What's in your Foo view? You can only have certain views in a widget. I'm not even sure you can instantiate a widget with a view created with code.

Comment: I had created a totally custom drawn dynamically updated visual thingy. Nice as a widget, but I guess I'll try now to render it to a bitmap in the `provider` and push it to a imageview that is supported.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly same way I did for my widget animation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I pretty much left my custom view intact, and implemented an ImageView for my widget, then rendered the view using the getDrawingCache()

```
MyView myView = new MyView(context);
myView.measure(150,150);
myView.layout(0,0,150,150);
myView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap=myView.getDrawingCache();
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.dial, bitmap);
```

Comment: I resolved the issue indeed by using a `ImageView`. I however didn't think of keeping my custom view. I integrated the renderingcode in the `Provider`. This is however a very nice solution!

Comment: In which method should I put this?

Comment: It's an amazing solution to use the bitmap of custom view.

Comment: Additional note: If your custom view extends a linear layout, then you need to measure with a maximum height constraint, else it doesn't expand to fill space.

Answer (score 14):

Another way to do this without using `getDrawingCache()` :

```
MyView myView = new MyView(this);
myView.measure(500, 500);
myView.layout(0, 0, 500, 500);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
myView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmap);
```

I used cache not to redraw all the view so I couldn't use the code above.
And I find it more elegant.
I hope it could be useful to someone.

Comment: I prefer this solution, as getDrawingCache used in the accepted solution is deprecated. In my case it worked better to use `myView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, EXACTLY))`

Answer (score 8):

You cannot have *ANY* custom view used in widget. In fact, even those android-predfined views are not all supported.

For detailed list of supported widgets/layouts, please read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout). Anything other than those documented cannot be placed in widgets.

Comment: Wow, that sucks... Why on earth did they do that?

Comment: Let me guess, since for widget, you (as widget developer) don't own the process/thread that render the widget, indeed, the home screen / launcher owns and renders it. Such limitation applies to prevent FC or poorly programmed widget kills the home screen app.

Comment: I saw this, and was rather disappointed. I figured there should be a way around it. I decided to share as this thread got my gears turning :)

Comment: @Chris. I feel the same as you. Depending on what you need to do, it might have alternatives. I personally developed a widget that play sprite animation, not that mature but the idea is to compose and swap the appearance using "setBitmap". http://andytsui.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/animating-android-home-screen-widget/ If you look for interactivity other than just 'click', then the standard home could not help, you have to do it in aHome or launcherpro or similar.

Answer (score 8):

see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

AnalogClock, Button, Chronometer, ImageButton, ImageView, ProgressBar and TextView are the supported views. For layouts you have to use FrameLayout, LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: Indeed, and subclasses of those (even your own) are NOT supported.