# Kankan.wheel on desktop widget

Tags: android, android-wheel

kankan.wheel (http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) is a library that I include in my project.

If I add wheel widget into activity layout - that's ok and work perfectly, but if I add this component into desktop widget layout - at moment adding widget to desktop I have this:

```
08-08 21:02:17.630: W/AppWidgetHostView(30529): Error inflating AppWidget       AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.snake.vahta.counter/com.snake.vahta.counter.V ahtaAppWidgetProvider}): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #89: Error inflating class kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
```

And widget doesn display, only string: Unable to show widget

My XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_margin="4dp"
  android:id="@+id/widgetFrameLayout"
  android:background="@drawable/background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_100k"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_10k"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_1k"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_100"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_dot"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_01"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/w_counter_001"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/total_sum" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop Widgets have a [limited set of allowed parts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).  The restrictions are necessary due to the potential security issues of allowing arbitrary code execution in the home screen.

Here's the relevant part of the appWidget Docs:

> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:
>
> FrameLayout
>
> LinearLayout
>
> RelativeLayout
>
> GridLayout
>
> And the following widget classes:
>
> AnalogClock
>
> Button
>
> Chronometer
>
> ImageButton
>
> ImageView
>
> ProgressBar
>
> TextView
>
> ViewFlipper
>
> ListView
>
> GridView
>
> StackView
>
> AdapterViewFlipper
>
> Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Comment: And what should I do in this case? I want different layout

Comment: @alexey Your only option is to work with the allowed layouts to craft an approximate analog, or a functionally similar design.

Comment: And I can use ImageView. I can initialize my view in program code and convert my view to bitmap. Like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062559/android-appwidget-with-custom-view-not-working