# Android simple widget to show image into ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget

i'm created simple widget extends from ImageView, in this simle code i want to set image into ImageView from layout xml,i want change background imageview image and change image to set other image into ImageView, but my problem in first time dont show image

1) i'm create new attribute into attr.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="CIconButton">
    <attr name="button_icon"     format="integer" />
    <attr name="background_icon" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

2) use CIconButton class into layout:

```
<!-- xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.sample.app.tpro" -->
<com.sample.widget.CIconButton
    android:id="@+id/imgv_update_selected_phones"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:button_icon="@drawable/icon_add_action" />
```

3) `CIconButton` class

```
public class CIconButton extends ImageView implements OnClickListener {
    private Drawable mSelectedBackground;

    public CIconButton(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }
    public CIconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CIconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CIconButton, defStyle, 0);
        mSelectedBackground = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CIconButton_button_icon);
        setImageDrawable(mSelectedBackground);
        a.recycle();
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

my custom widgets class dont show image set into layout xml, for example this class dont show `icon_add_action` from drawable

Comment: If you're extending `ImageView`, why not just use the `android:src` attribute, and let the `super` constructor take care of loading the image?

Comment: @Mike M. for get variable attr in `CIconButton class`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy .you should use android:src for displaying your icon as you are nyways extending Imageview

Comment: @MikeM. i want set background imageview and change image to set other image into ImageView

Comment: I still don't follow, but what you're trying to do is nothing different than would happen if you just used the `src` attribute. Whether your code sets the image, or the superclass sets the image, the result is the same. You might as well just let the `ImageView` class handle it.

Comment: check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062559/android-appwidget-with-custom-view-not-working

Comment: @Ramesh That post has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem resolved , i must be change second constructor as :

```
public CIconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

to:

```
public CIconButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

`this` call last this class constrctor