# Android : How to use custom view in Widget [Remote Views]

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview

Hi all android developers!
I want use Arc progress view in Widget to implement action progress circular timer. But, widget not support custom views. I found following way [Android: AppWidget with custom view not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062559/android-appwidget-with-custom-view-not-working) but always bitmap is null. Anybody know how to create custom view and get its bitmap without add it to window?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Android: AppWidget with custom view not working"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4062559/5742625)

Answer (score 2):

```
CustomView view = new CustomView(context);
view.measure(250, 250);
view.layout(0, 0, 250, 250);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.myImageView, bitmap);

//PUSH WIDGET UPDATE
```

Comment: better do `view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(250, EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(250, EXACTLY))`