# Error inflating class on external library component usage

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I create a simple widget that presents same data using Pie/Donut Chart (Circle Progress Bar). 
I wanted to use some external component so I chose:

```
com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
```

I placed the ArcProgress component to my widget.xml, I can see it clearly in Preview tab. There is no compilation, build or any other errors.
When I run application and put widget to home screen I face an exception:

```
W/AppWidgetHostView: updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sec.android.app.launcher-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sec.android.app.launcher-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sec.android.app.launcher-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
          at android.widget.RemoteViews.inflateView(RemoteViews.java:3844)
          at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:3808)
          at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.applyRemoteViews(AppWidgetHostView.java:456)
          at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:385)
          at com.android.launcher3.home.LauncherAppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java:161)
          at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:418)
          at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:136)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I think that there is some issue with gradle, because my first try was:

```
az.plainpie.PieView
```

and result was the same (but ClassNotFound was "az.plainpie.PieView" of course).

My widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
              android:background="#AA000000">
              <!--xmlns:plainpie="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"-->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/countryView"
        android:visibility="visible">

<!--        <az.plainpie.PieView
            android:id="@+id/globalValue"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            plainpie:inner_pie_padding="10"
            plainpie:percentage="75"
            plainpie:percentage_size="35"
            plainpie:inner_text_visibility="true"/>  -->

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
            android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:arc_bottom_text_size="10sp"
            app:arc_progress="55"
            app:arc_bottom_text="VALUE"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/countryText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="temp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pl.test.simplewidget'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0' 

    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'

    compile 'com.github.zurche:plain-pie:v0.2.1' //pie chart library zurche/plain-pie
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1' // circle progress bar

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I've tried clean project, uninstall application, use different phone.
My Android Studio has unchecked "Offline Work" and checked recommended "default gradle wrapper". I searched for solution but none of them solved my issue. Can you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use those custom view in your App Widgets as in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) says:

> Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with Layouts. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based
> on RemoteViews, which **do not support every kind of layout or view widget**.

Read for related question at [Android: AppWidget with custom view not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062559/android-appwidget-with-custom-view-not-working)

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right! Now I remember that I read that doc, but I just forgot about the exception you cited here. Thank you.